# How to connect Mongolab with MongoDb.Driver

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver, mlab

i'm testing mongolab with .netCore using MongoDb.Driver. 
I have this connection string

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@mymongolaburl:46367/somedatabase
```

And i'm connecting this way

```
        var connectionString = @"mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@mymongolaburl:46367/somedatabase";
        var databaseName = "somedatabase";
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        if (client != null)
        {
            _database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);

            _database.GetCollection<User>("User").InsertOne(new User {Name="Luke Skywalker" });
        }
```

It is not working 'cause it says the database name is invalid, if i use the connection string without the database name

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@mymongolaburl:46367
```

I get a timeout execption.
I Already connected to database using Robo 3T.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day i found how to do that in this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/])

The The solution is to specify which is database in the connection string

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@mymongolaburl:46367/?authSource=somedatabase
```

Thank you!